# When I run this code, the output is 1,2,3,0 but I don't understand why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int, int[]);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int i;
    fun(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)-1,arr);
    int x = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)-1);
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void fun(int n, int arr[])
{
    int *p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < n)
        p = &arr[i];
    *p = 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems you set the last element of the array to `0`. The line `*p = 0;` is probably doing that. Have you checked what value `n` has in `fun`? What output did you *expect* to get?

Comment: What were you expecting?  All elements of the array to be zero?

Answer (score 3):

1. `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` returns the number of elements in `arr`, which is 4 in this case.
2. `n` is `3` (`4-1`) here, so `i++ < n` is true if `i` just before evaluating this expression is `2` or less, and is false if it is `3` or more.
3. If the value of `i` was `2` before evaluating `i++ < n`, `i` become `3` after evaluating this expression.
4. Then, the address of `arr[3]` is stored to `p`.
5. Now `i` i `3`, `i++ < n` is false and the loop ends.
6. `arr[3]` becomes `0` thanks to `*p = 0;`
7. What is passed as the argument `arr` of `fun()` is the address of the first element of `arr` in `main()`, so the fourth element of it became `0`.
8. Finally, the elements of `arr` are printed.